# Allow Duplicate Screen Name

Tags: members, import

I'm importing new members using the Member Import Utility, but get errors for duplicate screen_name. These members won't be posting so screen name is not used and email is username.

I've added a condition in Validate.php and EE_Form_validation.php to stop the validation:

```
if (1 == 2 && strtolower($this->cur_screen_name) != strtolower($this->screen_name))
```

this works okay when a single member registers via front end form, but not when importing XML file.

so I then hacked tools_utilities.php, commenting out:

```
                            /*
                        case 'screen_name':
                            $this->validate->screen_name = $tag->value;
                            if ( ! in_array($tag->value, $s))
                            {
                                $s[] = $tag->value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this->errors[] = array(lang('duplicate_screen_name').$tag->value);
                            }
                            break;
                            */
```

Seems to work, but has anyone had other issues with this? it would be good to know before I import 10K members.

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to hack tools_utilities to generate a random screen name? Or just use the email address as screen name?

Comment: I'm importing from a spreadsheet that has a mixed bag of members, can't see reason to auto generate, I could easily add these random names before import. I like your thinking if I was importing on a regular basis.

Comment: I can't really see a reason skipping the duplicates check will cause a problem going forward.

Comment: thanks Rob for your feedback - I imported 10K members without any problems. And it's a hack that won't cause any big issues if forgotten on future system updates.

Comment: Or you could add an $i++ number onto the screenname for duplicates.

Comment: I would echo what Rob has suggested, if screen_name isn't used just append a number to it for each time you encounter a duplicate. :)

Comment: If anyone has an alternative method they'd be able to demonstrate in an answer, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more inclined to follow Robs suggestion. I don't know if this would work (Need to test it), but maybe something along the lines of this:

```
case 'screen_name':
$this->validate->screen_name = $tag->value;
if ( ! in_array($tag->value, $s))
{
        $s[] = $tag->value;
}
else
{
    $emailUserName = $member->children['email']->value;
    if ( ! in_array($emailUserName, $s))
        {
            $s[] = $tag->$emailUserName;
        }
        else{
            $this->errors[] = array(lang('duplicate_screen_name').$tag->value);
        }
}
break;
```

instead of commenting it out completely...  Just make a NOTE in your CP sidebar notes or something along the lines of when/where/why you made the change so you can trace back to issues that may come up. I would think that "forcing" the email as the username would be better than ignoring it though. Especially since you are using the email as username anyway.

Like I said, debug that write up though.   ;)